# Pink questions in the list

Tags: support, tag-watching

In the  question list we see that there are some  questions  which are pink. What is the reason of this situation?

Comment: Do you happen to have some [favorite tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/favorites/info)? Maybe what you see as "pink" questions which have favorite tags. (I believe this depends on the design/color scheme of the site. On [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) the questions in favorite tags are light blue.

Comment: As with all such questions, a screenshot is worth the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions which are in different color are those ones, which have one of your [watched tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tag-watching/info). (This feature used to be called *favorited tags*, but it [was later renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching).)

From [What do “watched tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)

> - Questions with these tags become highlighted on the front page.

- Questions with new activity are shown on [stackexchange.com/filters](//stackexchange.com/filters/).
- In the review queues, questions from these tags are shown to you before other questions.

The actual color is different for various sites - it depends on the design and color scheme of the actual site. (For example, they are highlighted with different color on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) than on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions). The highlighting can differ even between main site and meta - for example, if you have some watched tags [here on MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions) you can see that they get grey-ish background color.)

On MO, it looks something like this:

[image: screenshot from the main site]

And this is from Meta MathOverflow:

[image: screenshot from the meta site]

---

After inspecting the site, I found `tagged-interesting{background-color:var(--yellow-050)}` both on the main site and on meta. You can see various colors used on Stack Exchange sites in the [Stacks Project - Colors](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/colors). (It seems that people perceive colors differently. And it might also depend a bit on the setup of your monitor. The background color was described as *pink* in this question and as *yellow* in [another question here on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5072).

On Meta Stack Exchange you can find also some discussions related to changing the background color - however, they are rather old, so the answers might be outdated: [How can I change the CSS for a question that has a favorite tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77181), [Define your own color of tagged-interesting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66592), [Double-intensity shading for questions with >1 Interesting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49704). There is also a similar post on Meta Stack Overflow: [The highlight colour for interested tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345045). I will remind also a post on this meta about getting MO to look closer to "ye olde version": [How can I customize site in my browser to get “old feel” look of MathOverflow?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4022)

---

If you're not sure where to find (or change) your watched tags, you can consult the [FAQ post mentioned above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173). I will add a link to my post on Mathematics Meta, which contains also some screenshots: [How do I follow tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863#27881)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you happen to have the privilege to see deleted questions or answers, they are given a reddish background to differentiate them from the rest.

Comment: @Dorias  Thank you. But I found  a  non  deleted question with this  situation. I directly asked the moderator via  "flag" that  question.

Comment: Ali, I don't see what you are seeing. All I can think of is that it's an issue with your computer, and that maybe clearing the cache of your web browser might help (but I'm not the best person to dispense technical advice).

Comment: @ToddTrimble  Thank  you. I will contact you if it is not solved.

Comment: @ToddTrimble (and François G. Dorais) My best guess is that this is highlighting of the questions in [favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do). Let's wait to see whether the OP confirms that this is what they have in mind.

Comment: @MartinSleziak   Yes,Yes, Exactly. I went to my  preference I realized that the  pink question has  a tag in my "favorite tags". I thank you and  all other moderators for  your  great activities in this  wonderful  site MO.

Comment: @ToddTrimble  My problem is  solved thanks.

Comment: @Dorias Now  my problem is  solved. thanks.

Comment: Deleted questions get a reddish background when you *view* them, but they do not appear at all on the *question list*.