# What is yellow about?

Tags: support, tag-watching

Some questions asked at MO are emphasized with the color yellow. What does this mean, and how can one emphasize a question that way?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible that you're asking about watched tags and ignored tags? See: [Pink questions in the list](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3349) and [Vanishing questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3378). There is also some info in the tag-info for [tag-watching](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tag-watching/info) and [ignored-tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/ignored-tags/info).

Comment: If you can provide a screen cap of such a "yellow" question, then we can answer better.  In my case, questions with a tag from my "watched" list are surrounded with yellow.

Comment: Sponsored questions have been introduced after the Prosus acquisition. /s

Comment: @GeraldEdgar https://www.dropbox.com/s/4e4j4lgvgx5xcj0/Screen%20Shot%202021-06-17%20at%2019.45.25.png?dl=0

Comment: Similarly as on the main site, it is better to include details in the question rather than just in comments. So I included the screenshot into the question - after adding the screenshot it is clear that this is highlighting for questions with the tags you're watching. You could check you're watched tags in the sidebar on the right or in your preferences, I have previously added also some screenshots here: [How do I follow tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863#27881)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no, they will be pinned at the top above other questions, when they are rolled out ;-) (also a big /s)